# Slider Caption issues (Orbit Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone knows the best way to make a caption like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA2NH.png? I've tried with Firebug and I achieved this https://i.stack.imgur.com/alvpe.png but when I actually put the code in the html page it doesn't work. Does anyone knows how to make something like in the picture?

Thank you :)

Comment: Edit : here's my page http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/localh0st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i checked your page its nice. Here is the link for caption of your slider.

Try This: http://jsfiddle.net/CFtEe/3/

Ask me if you have any problem.

Comment: Wow thank you so much but the problem is that I don't know how to implement this design with the slider, the instructions are not that clear to me.  http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider . Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: Welcome! I'll download orbit slider today & add the caption like this & will send you.

Comment: Ah lovely! Thank you so much!

The latest version can be founded here : https://github.com/zurb/orbit

Comment: Is it better if I give you my email?